LWC Custom lightning-record-form does not display the fields
I've created a custom lightning-record-form because I need to implement a custom field bellow a specific custom field.
For the first test, I just created a lwc that extends the LightningRecordForm, to see if everything is working, but no field is being displayed.
So I created the lwc "customRecordForm":
import LightningRecordForm from 'lightning/recordForm';

export default class CustomRecordForm extends LightningRecordForm {
    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();

        console.log('connectedCallback called');
    }
}

And I added it in another LWC component:
<template>
    <c-custom-record-form
        record-id={recordId}
        object-api-name="Account"
        layout-type="Full"
        columns="1"
        mode="view">
    </c-custom-record-form>
</template>

In the console tab I can see my log "connectedCallback called" and no error is displayed, but still no field is being displayed.
If I replace the c-custom-record-form for a lightning-record-form it works fine.
What can be missing?

Extending this component isn't supported. If it were, it'd be in the documentation, as it is for lightning-datatable. Instead, you'll have to build something with lightning-record-edit-form and lightning-record-view-form.
